# How to run auth check in my express route before uploading a file with multer

Tags: node.js, express, upload, token, multer

Working on my backend in *node.js* and *express*, newly using *multer* to upload a file.

I want to check if my user has a valid token: If yes he can upload a file, if not, get a 401 back. With my following code, this works, but the file still gets uploaded, even if the user has no valid token.

I guess my check should happen before the parameter `upload.single('image')`, but I don't really know how. **Any tips?**

My code:

```
router.post("/", upload.single('image'), (req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.isAuth) {
      res.status(401).json({error: "Unauthenticated"});
    } else {
      console.log('file', req.file);
      res.status(200).json({resultFileName: req.file.filename });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this but i haven't tested it and haven't used express in a while.

```
router.post("/", (req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.isAuth)
      return res.status(401).json({error: "Unauthenticated"});
    next();
}, upload.single('image'), (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('file', req.file);
    res.status(200).json({resultFileName: req.file.filename });
});
```

Comment: Just did! I I am kinda new to this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Create a middlewares or helper and create authorize.js file in it and add jwt auth code in it like below

**authorize.js**

```js
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

module.exports = {
    jwtAuth: (req, res, next) => {

    //Jwt verification code according to your configuration

   }
}
```

And import that file in your route folder and use it like below

**Users.js**

```js
const authorize = require('../middlewares/authorize')


router.post("/", authorize.jwtAuth, upload.single('image'), (req, res, next) => {
      console.log('file', req.file);
      res.status(200).json({resultFileName: req.file.filename });
});
```

Comment: Actually more than what I wanted, but probably the cleaner version here ;). Thanks for pitching in!